# PnP Provisioning Tenant how to migrate one tenant to another location

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, pnp

Is there a possibility to migrate all resources from one tenant to another? How Could we Migrate them to deploy from the testing environment to the production environment?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at the Tenant Migration sample in PnP PowerShell.

Here is a documentation about [Tenant.Migration](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/tree/master/Samples/Tenant.Migration)